# Inserting data into tables by comparing

Tags: c#, random

I am using the tables to store subject names of `one` section of a course. My question is, how can I go about inserting the subject names from one table to another table in such a way that no two subjects can occur at the same hour.

Example :

```
Table-1

Hour     Subject-name

1           C#
2           Java
3           OS
4           C++
5           DBMS
```

I need to enter the same set of values to another table say, `table-2` in such a way :

```
Table-2

Hour            Subject-name

1                OS
2                DBMS
3                C#
4                Java
5                C++
```

I have used to shuffle operation for a list in order to shuffle the elements randomly. But, there is a possibility of occurrence of the same subject twice.

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does table 1 contain Distinct Subject Names ? If so, the Shuffle should only randomly order the elements and should not result in any duplicates.

Comment: By duplicate, you mean a record in table 2 that is the same in table 1 ?

Comment: Yes, table-1 contains Distinct subjects. Also, yes, shuffle does not result in any duplicates. But the problem with the shuffle function is: Since it is shuffled randomly, there is no guarantee that table-1 and table-2 will have a unique order all the time. @user3185569

Comment: I basically need to create a second table by using the values present in the first table but I have to make sure that the order of the values in the two tables are not the same. @user3185569

Comment: You need to avoid have all items the same, or even one same item in table1 and table 2 will violate your rule ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Shuffle** and then check if your **rule is violated** and try again.

Below is one approach of doing that:

```
Random rng = new Random();
private IList<Course> SmartShuffle(IList<Course> oldList)
{
    IList<Course> newList = new List<Course>();
    while (true)
    {
        var randomOrder = oldList.OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).ToList();

        int counter = 0;
        foreach(var course in oldList)
        {
            newList.Add(new Course() { Name = randomOrder[counter].Name, Hour = course.Hour });

            counter++;
        }

        int differenceCount = newList.Count(n => oldList.Any(o => o.Name == n.Name && o.Hour != n.Hour));

        // leave only one of the below if statements

        // case at least 1 element should be different
        if (differenceCount > 0)
            break;

        // case all elements must be different
        if (differenceCount == oldList.Count)
            break;
    }

    return newList;
}

public class Course
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Hour { set; get; }
}
```